# How can I make my shell script executable

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, executable

I wrote a shell script which opens some directories and runs some script, I run this bash file by terminal (`bash filename.sh`), how can I make it clickable?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/668079/how-to-make-a-sh-file-executable-by-double-click-in-ubuntu-14-04)?

Comment: create a desktop entry, and specify the running command of this desktop entry to your script full path. see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal)

Comment: Did you put a `#!` line in your script?  It should be "clickable" (not a good term) if you can run it from the command-line as just `filename.sh`.

Comment: What does this script look like? Which desktop environment are you running? Unity? Mate? Gnome?

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the following [shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang) line to the top of your code.

`#!/bin/bash`

You also need to ensure that the script has executable permissions by running:

`chmod a+x <filename>.sh`

Answer (score 3):

You first need to start your script with

'#!/bin/bash '

and save it as <*filename*>.sh Also make sure that you keep the permissions as a+x i.e all users can execute the script.